# FacebookWeb or FacebookWebMVC

Tags: facebook, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, nuget-package

can someone briefly explain what the difference is between these packages? The project pages don't seem to offer any clues?

I am creating an MVC application where i would like to associate facebook credentials with a user's profile. In terms of functionality, i need to simply post to the user's wall. So not sure which package would be best to do this with..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this package follows conventions that are used for most NuGet packages, FacebookWebMVC will be the one for working with ASP.NET MVC.